# Clementine Remote with UFW

Tags: networking, 16.04, firewall, ufw, clementine

So I installed Clementine Remote for Android, to connect to my computer running Ubuntu 16.04. I am also running UFW, and when I tried to connect to Clementine, my Android Device was giving an error saying: 'Could not reach host'.

The only way I was able to connect to Clementine was to manually allow port 5500 through UFW. My question is, is there any other way to allow this connection to Clementine remote without allowing port 5500 manually, or disabling UFW?

If not, is there any real danger to allow this port to be open or is it better to keep it closed?

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any type of firewall, the only way to allow connections is by opening up that port. If your app allows it, you can change the port it uses. There really is no problem with that port being open, technically. Because it's the default port for the service, an attacker may bulk scan hosts to see if that port is open, but that's only an issue if there is a known vulnerability in the service itself. Either way, whether you use the default port or a custom one, you will have to open that port in your firewall (UFW).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response! I guess I will just have to open the port through UFW. Clementine does allow to change the port it uses, do you have any suggestions on safe ports to use, or are they all about the same?

Comment: They're all the same, but only root can open up ports 1-102(4? 3? somewhere in the 1020 range). I usually just pick a random 5 digit number below 65535. Remember to click the little checkmark next to my answer if this solved your problem :)